# SVN Removing branch and add it again with the same name

Tags: svn, branch, svn-trunk

In remote SVN repository, I have dev branch and trunk.

Every fortnight, we are removing dev branch and making a new dev branch from trunk on the same URL. 
But in this process we are loosing the changes/not merged code in old dev branch.

Three questions-

1. The changes that i am loosing, i am having the same locally. How can I commit that again to the new dev branch? (without checking out the new dev and manually copying it.)
2. Is there any better approach? (Except from merge everything first to trunk then create new dev. that is not possible in our case).
3. Every fortnight, instead of creating a new branch I can also merge the trunk back to dev. But we always get lots of conflict and its really hard and manual step to resolve them. is this possible to automate this in any way?

Comment: Why do you do this? *"Every fortnight, we are removing dev branch and making a new dev branch from trunk on the same URL."*

Comment: To get the latest stage of trunk to start the development.